# Karate check if a phrase available in the response

Tags: karate

I've a response

```
{ errors: [
       {
        code: 123,
        reason: "this is the reason1 is dynamically generated"
     }  ,
     {
        code: 234,
        reason: "this is the reason2 for another random reason"
     }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Now when I validate this response
I use following

```
...
...    
And match response.errors[*].reason contains "this is the reason"
```

This validation fails, because there is an equality check for `complete String` for every `reason` with the phrase mentioned in the condition. `this is reason1`
I tried few wild cards but didn't work either, how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `each`:

```
And match each response.errors[*].reason contains "this is reason"
```

Refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#match-each

Comment: Now I realized my example  data was confusing Let me update it.,,, But I do not want to validate that each reason code contains the  `phrase`.  All I wanted was that there should be atleast one `reason` which contains this `phrase`